# How to use Get-AzureADUser -Filter Parameter with Objects Saved in a Variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, odata

I'm having difficulty using the Filter parameter to query AAD or MSoL Online using the built in filter paramater in Get-AzureADUser or Get-MsolUser or Get-User

I've imported a csv file and saved the file into an array $users with the structure:

EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName, ObjectID

Only the EmailAddress column has values. I've tried constructing a foreach loop to go through the array and add values to the other columns.

```
$users = import-csv .\users.csv 
foreach($user in $users){
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "PrimarySMTPAddress eq '$($user.EmailAddress)'" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectID
}
```

The trouble is that the command nested in the loop does not return any values.

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "PrimarySMTPAddress eq 'user@contoso.com'" | Select-Object ObjectID, UserPrincipalName
```

Does work. It looks like the Filter command doesn't ever read the values contained in the array $users

**Questions:**

What's the correct syntax for the Filter parameter so I can loop through the array?

How do I save the values obtained from the Get-AzureADUser cmdlet into my constructed array so that I cannot export it to a file?

Comment: Are you sure Azure AD users have a property with name `PrimarySMTPAddress`? I do not recall this being a property, I do know you have `mail` and `proxyAddresses`.

Comment: Yes its a valid property. If I input a single email address into the filter it does return the Azure AD object.

Answer (score 1):

Older issue, but you gave me a clue that helped me resolve the same issue right now. Need to backtick the single quotes:

Get-AzureADUser -Filter "mail eq `'$($user.EmailAddress)`'"

Comment: Sorry, my example was using the mail attribute, but as long as PrimarySMTPAddress is a valid attribute, it should work